# How to resize width to minimum possible using GUI

Tags: qt, resize, window, qt-designer, minimum-size

I use QtDesigner. I resized window width as small as possible using QtDesigner. But when window executed there is possible to make its width smaller. So I want to add to constructor code which made width as minimum possible using GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`resize`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt/qwidget.html#size-prop) the window to [`minimumSizeHint()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt/qwidget.html#minimumSizeHint-prop) in the constructor:

```
resize(minimumSizeHint());
```

This will shrink the window to minimum size.

If you want to only shrink in width, then you can do something like:

```
resize(minimumSizeHint().width(), hight());
```